# SAS - How to make dataset wide to long when some values are missing?

Tags: sas, dataset, transpose

I have a dataset that looks basically like this:

| LOCID | Name | Addtl Loc 1 | Addtl Loc 2 | Addtl Loc 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | B | 2 |  |  |
| 1 | C | 2 | 4 |  |

And I would like to make it look like this:

| LOCID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | F |
| 2 | A | F |
| 3 | A | F |
| 5 | A | F |
| 1 | B | M |
| 2 | B | M |
| 1 | C | F |
| 2 | C | F |
| 4 | C | F |

So, I'd like to keep the attributes for each person but have a row for each of their locations. I also don't currently have a unique ID or any variable to identify each of the people but I could make one. I'm working in SAS. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

I have been looking up wide to long methods but am having trouble understanding them.

Comment: Do you have gender in your input data as well, or how will you derive it in the output dataset?
Also, does your input dataset really have spaces in the variable names like `Addtl Loc 1`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could just use a DO LOOP to transpose the data.
So assuming your input data set has LOCID and ADD_LOCID1 to ADD_LOCID3 plus any other variables, such as NAME and GENDER, you could just do the following to add an extra observation for every non-missing value found in the extra locid variables.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array list add_locid1 - add_locid3;
  output;
  do index=1 to dim(list);
    locid = list[index];
    if not missing(locid) then output;
  end;
  drop index add_locid1-add_locid3 ;
run;
```

Comment: I was not able to get this to work unfortunately but figured out a workaround. Thank you for taking the time to respond though! (I ended up creating new datasets for each of the people with additional locations, created a new location variable and then concated the datasets back together).